# Algorithm for a like '%term%' search

Tags: python, algorithm, search

Suppose I have a db column `filepath` and I want to do a contains search, for example:

```
matches = []
for filepath in filepaths:
    if "mutan" in filepath.lower():
        matches.append(filepath)
```

Is there anyway at all to optimize this algorithm? I am open to storing ancillary structs or other methods, but what might be some practical ways to do this?

The only thing I can think of is to tokenize the filepath so that I have something like:

```
/my/new/File.jpg ==>
# 1 char
['e', 'g', 'f', 'i', 'j', 'm', 'l', '/', 'n', 'p', 'w', 'y', '.']
# 2 char
['/n', '/m', 'le', 'y/', 'w/', '/f', 'jp', 'ne', 'e.', 'il', 'fi', 'ew', 'my', '.j', 'pg']
# etc...
```

And then do a lookup with the term I have to see  if it exists there, but to tokenize a word by every letter seems like it would take forever to do and take up tons of space as well. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I'd expect substring / instring search to already be optimized in the library code.  When I've had to write my own code in C++ I searched the haytack using memchar ( needle[0] ) then did a memcmp.  If matched, done else do memchar again.  The library code is probably better than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of common algorithms are the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm
 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm  there are others too.

Depending on your search needs you might also like to implement a small bloom filter, we use a 32 bit mask for each string we might want to search, setting bit 1 for 'a' present, bit 2 for 'b' etc.  This allows us to quickly eliminate complete database rows and not search all.

To get more specific, we would need to know what you want to optimise for, memory, cpu etc. scanning even a few Gb is pretty quick on high end CPUs these days.

Comment: thanks this is very helpful. What would be the difference in implementing either (1) the Rabin Karp; or (2) Moore; or (3) Bloom? Is one particularly better suited than the other for a contains search, or why would one be chosen over the other? I'm using a Desktop mac, so I have a lot of cpu/mem, and the file is about 1GB size, so it can all fit in memory.

Comment: @david542 Cannot really comment on implementing as dont speak Python. We did test various algorithms in C++ and found the bloom was easy and a good fit for our short strings where one letter would often not be present at all in a string. Bloom would not save much for long string sequences. We also wanted to search more for '%c%a%r%o%l' over multiple columns, similar to your other question on multithreaded search.   Tip: if you want the easy path, look at using sqlite in your app and leave to to that.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `"mutan" in filepath.lower()`, you might consider:

```
import re
pat = re.compile("mutan", re.I)

if pat.search(filepath) is not None:
```

This combines the substring search with the case-ignoring. I have a program that uses this with a more complex pattern and it can filter the names of a directory tree as fast as they can be read.